# .co.za Nameserver issue

Tags: nameserver

I am trying to change the nameservers on a .co.za domain to the private nameservers set up on my dedicated server, but I get the error below. The nameservers work fine for a .co.uk domain name.

Not sure what to do, any help will be more than appreciated.

The Error is:

Command failed; CheckDNS: ns1.wpserver.com not authoritative SOA.

If you wish to change the nameservers for your .co.za domain, please make sure that the domain has a valid zone in the new nameservers configuration. Please contact your new host if you are still having problems.

Comment: You did not give us enough information about your working environment like: OS, nameserver used, etc..

Answer (score 2):

The nameserver you've specified (ns1.wpserver.com) is not authoritative for the domain. You need to configure your nameservers with your zone before you update the co.za delegation.

Answer (score 0):

If it says not auth SOA, edit the dns SOA record for that domain and plop in the first nameserver you use. (want to use)